# Reduced products of (abelian and triangulated) categories: references?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, terminology, triangulated-categories, ultrapowers

For a filter $U$ on a set $X$ and for a family of categories $C_x$ indexed by $X$ I would like to consider the (corresponding categorical version of) reduced product of $C_x$ (for $x\in X$) with respect to $U$ (is there a special name for reduced products of this type? certainly, they generalize ultraproducts/ultrapowers of categories). Did anybody consider products of this type (in particular, for abelian and triangulated categories)?